# gdb can't recognize the format of a running program

Tags: ubuntu, gdb

I got a program (not a shell script) on my Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit), it runs fine, however, when I attach to it using gdb, got message **File format not recognized**.  This is quite puzzling. Any idea why?  Thanks.

```
# gdb -p 25016
GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://bugs.launchpad.net/gdb-linaro/>.
Attaching to process 25016
"/home/test/engine": not in executable format: **File format not recognized**


# file /home/test/engine
engine: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
# which gdb
/usr/bin/gdb
# file /usr/bin/gdb
/usr/bin/gdb: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x8cd6c593fd6ffe6fd72266bf3d3407ea599b8143, stripped
root@jin1-HP:~/projs/jsStress_compile
```

Answer (score 1):

> GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04

This GDB is quite old (current GDB version is 7.7). Try to reproduce this problem with newer GDB.

If the problem persists, it's possible that

- there is a bug in GDB
- the `engine` program is an intentionally corrupt `ELF` file, employing some kind of anti-debugging / anti-reverse-engineering technique.

If you can make the `engine` binary available somewhere, I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I checked out gdb source and built the version 7.7 and used it to look at the software "engine" but still got the same story.   Since it's unlikely to be a bug in GDB, my guess is that  there is some kind of anti-debugging thing there.  Unfortunately I am not supposed to share it with other. Thanks for the offer though.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this program is a Release Version, Not Debug Version.

Comment: For Release version, I don't expect to see any symbols, but there shouldn't be the message "not in executable format: **File format not recognized**".  Thanks.

Comment: GDB is perfectly capable of debugging release binaries. This answer is completely bogus.